# cakephp 1.3 file download not working

Tags: cakephp-1.3

i am try to download uploaded file.upload successfully done but i could not download this file,here my script

Controller:
    function download($id) {
        $this->view = 'Media';

```
    $name = trim($id, '.gsm');
    $params = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'name' => $name,
        'download' => true,
        'extension' => 'gsm',
        'mimeType' => array('gsm' => 'audio/gsm'),
        'path' => WWW_ROOT.'files'.DS.'vr'.DS,
    );
    print_r($params);
    $this->set($params);
}
```

View:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Download', array('controller' => 'AudioDownloads', 'action' => 'download', $cdrCus['CdrCus']['uniqueid'].'.gsm')); ?>
```

Show Error

```
download/1489637104.427.gsm' was not found on this server.
```

How can i fix it?can any body help me?

Answer (score 1):

Finally Solved this Problem

```
function download($id=NULL) {
    $this->view = 'Media';
    $gid = trim($id);
    $data = explode(".gsm", $gid);
    $names = $data[0];
    $params = array(
        'id' => $gid,
        'name' => $names,
        'extension' => 'gsm',
        'mimeType' => array(
            'docx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
            'gsm' => 'audio/gsm'
            ), 
        'path' => WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'vr' . DS,
    );
    $this->set($params);
}
```